# Remove firefox home page message of the day

Tags: firefox, homepage

How to change the "message of the day" on the firefox browser home page ?

What I mean by "message of the day" is the quote shown under the search bar in the home page, as shown in the picture below :

[image]

For instance, is there any options in `about:config` that can be modified for that purpose ?

By inspecting `about:home` sources (`view-source:about:home`) it looks like it is shown in the `snippetContainer` element. So I looked up in the about:config for snippet-related settings and only found the `browser.aboutHomeSnippets.updateUrl` key.

I tried to update it with another url (for instance `http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=html` ) with no success ?

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not simply want to use a different site for your homepage? Google.com for instance?

Answer (score 2):

If you hover your mouse over the "Message of the day", you should see a small "X" button appear. Click that and the message should not appear again, even if you close and restart the browser. Just tested under Firefox 52.0.2 64 Bit for Linux.

If that doesn't help, consider getting rid of the start page altogether. I know many people use it to have a search bar at startup, but it isn't needed since typing anything in the address bar will send it to your default search engine, anyway. You can get rid of the start page by going to *Preferences > General > Start page* and typing in *about:blank*.