# How to re-enable firefox homepage snippets (message of the day)?

Tags: firefox, homepage

How to enable homepage snippets after disabling it via the close button?

The snippets are messages that appear in the default home page, below the search bar. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I can't find any option in preferences or `about:config` page but 
only`aboutHomeSnippets`.
This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1200924/735220) shows how to disable the message.

Comment: Set home page to default as previous.

Comment: @Biswa: thank you for commenting. Already tried setting to default home page (even after changing to another page before) but no result.

Comment: Delete pref.js file in Firefox user folder. This may delete all preferences.

Comment: @Biswa: just tried deleting pref.js and no result. Refreshing Firefox should restore resolve, but this is such a cosmetic issue that not worth the work.

Comment: Grepping for "snip" in Firefox user folder yield no useful results.

Comment: Appears that the problem solved itself - and Firefox didn't update - only noticeable change is that different snippets appeared. Should I delete/answer this question?